# How to parse json to get all values of a specific key within an array json?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble trying to get a list of values from a specific key inside an json array using python. Using the JSON example below, I am trying to create a list which consists only the values of the  `price` key. Original JSON:

```
{
   "data": 
       [
           {
               "id": 72292977, 
               "name": "Smart Cook inox 316 410ml EDA0309", 
               "price": 199000 
           }, 
           {
               "id": 73124602, "sku": "7494611465205", 
               "name": "Lock&Lock Vacuum Bottle LHC6180SLV (800ML)", 
               "price": 293000
           }
       ]
   "paging": 
       {
           "total": 1876, 
           "per_page": 48, 
           "current_page": 1
       }
}
```

Expected:

```
["199000 ", "293000"]
```

Below is the code of my approach:

```
import json
try:
    with open("data.json", 'r') as f:
        contents = json.load(f)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

How can I get the `price` value after loading json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the answer above, but it gets the information from the json file itself, rather than pasting the file as a variable.

```
import json

# Open json export file
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    contents = json.load(f)

data = contents['data']

prices = []

for id in data:
    prices.append(id['price'])

print(prices)
```

Output:

```
[199000, 293000]
```